# Asp.NET Core API - Change field names

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can API return customised names?

For example:

```
<UserInfo>
    <name>aaaaaa</name>
    <endpoints>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>2</int>
    </endpoints>
</UserInfo>
```

is generated from code

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string name;
    public int[] endpoints;
}
```

I'd like to return this:

```
<User name="aaaaaa">
    <endpoints>
         <endpoint>1</endpoint>
         <endpoint>2</endpoint>
    </endpoints>
</User>
```

How can I

1. Rename UserInfo to User
2. Define name as attribute
3. Rename fields in endpoints array to `endpoint`?

I've tried using `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`, but nothing changed.

EDIT: Method I use to get output:

```
    // GET api/info
    [HttpGet("info")]
    public IActionResult GetInfo([FromHeader] string auth)
    {
        if (HasAccess(auth, Endpoints.Info))
        {
            return new ObjectResult(Database.GetInfoAboutUser(auth));
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I answered number 1, I could not understand numbers 2 and 3, therefore I could not help.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Thank you! It would be great if you had idea how to do instead of `... <name>aaaa</name>` this `<User name="aaaaa">...</User>`. 3. means, that items in the array are named `int` now, I want to change their name.

Comment: Please post what code you use to generate that XML, and try my answer for number one and three to be sure that we may get rid of it.

Comment: I use the asp.net core web api - I just return object from controller and asp serializes it on its own. I'll edit answer and add source code tomorrow, as I don't have access to the source code now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: OK, then we can try further when you post the code.

Comment: I've added example. `GetInfoAboutUser` returns the object `UserInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 questions in one question. However:

Number one:

I guess this is what you want:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "User")]
public class UserInfo
{
...
}
```

Number three:

```
int[] values = { 1, 2, 17, 8 };

XDocument doc = new XDocument();
doc.Add(new XElement("endpoints", values.Select( x=> new XElement("item", x))));
```